# What Happens to an Eidolon's Equipment When It is Dismissed or Dies?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, eidolon

If you give an eidolon equipment, does it go with it when it returns to their home plane, or does it just kind of drop off of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should go with them (summoned creatures with equipment, like powerful angels, demons, and devils come with their equipment and don't drop it when they leave, after all), but keep in mind that you share item slots with your eidolon - you can't both gain the benefits of magical amulets, for example, at the same time.

Reference for shared item slots, [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons#TOC-Link-Ex-):

> In addition, magic items interfere with the summoner’s connection to his eidolon. As a result, the summoner and his eidolon share magic item slots.

This should also be in the Advanced Player's Guide, in the Summoner's class description (specifically, in the section that describes how Eidolons work at the end).

Comment: Where does it say that the eidolon and the summoner share item slots?

Comment: @JonClaus answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

### All equipment will vanish with your eidolon

Summoned creatures, in Pathfinder, [are not real](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/87861/21153). Eidolons, however, are exceptions to this, they are real manifestations combined into a creature by the summoner.  [James Jacobs](http://paizo.com/people/JamesJacobs) (Paizo's Creative Director) has answered this [specific question on his "Ask Anything" thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=298?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#14851) at paizo forums:

> *Do items carried/worn by the creature representing the eidolon come over with it when it's summoned?*
>
> In the case of an eidolon, it initially comes over naked. Any gear or items given to it stay with it, vanishing into some inaccessible void when the eidolon is gone and coming back the next time it's summoned. Items can't be utilized while in this "void" but neither can they be destroyed.
>
> *What about items that the eidolon is carrying when it's dismissed (or dies) and is sent back to its home plane?*
>
> Those items go with the eidolon, and come back the next time it's summoned. Creatures being grappled or otherwise detained by the eidolon do not vanish; they're released when the eidolon goes away.